# Having trouble with importing files in Python

Tags: python, file, import, directory, package

Python 3.8
MacOS

I am trying to import different modules inside a package and I am getting ModuleNotFoundError or ImportError when trying to use relative imports.

I have a folder called "practice_dir" with the following structure:

```
(base) or ƒ(~/practice_dir) >> tree
.
├── __init__.py
├── dir_1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── file_1.py
│   └── subdir
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── subfile.py
├── dir_2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── file_2.py
└── parent_file.py
```

It was mentioned online that once I have an **init** file on every folder containing modules than the absolute imports would start from the parent package

And relative imports would be using . or .. notation

Here's some of the examples I tried

*In file_1:*

```
from dir_2 import file_2
```

> ModuleNotFoundError

```
from .dir_2 import file_2
```

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

It's the same if I do the same thing in dir_2, and dir_1/subfolder

The **init**.py files are empty right now, I tried to include imports to the files but that didn't work.

I've been looking at some questions posted online and on youtube, there seems to be various ways and one guy even mentioned that you don't need the **init** files if you have python 3.3+

Been battling hard with this, any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Where is your *main.py* script? If you put it in the same parent directory that contains the top-level package directory, the imports should all work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the file to the python path at runtime:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'path/to/file')

import file
```

Comment: Still produces a module error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/or/practice_dir/dir_1/file_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dir_2.file_2 as f2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dir_2'`

Comment: @orie Updated my answer. It should work now

Comment: The `sys.path` trick works well but isn't there a way to make it work with the usual syntax? I thought directories in python can be represented as packages

Comment: @orie I already gave you the answer in my comment on your question. Why don't you try it?

Comment: @orie I looked around for other ways to do it, but this was the only way I saw that consistently worked. There might be better solutions though, but this works for me!

Comment: @DapperDuck Every python application has a *main.py* script that is used to start it. The import system is specifically designed so that the directory that contains *main.py* is automatically inserted at the beginning of `sys.path`. This guarantees that all other imports within the package will work as expected. It's a common mistake to put *main.py* inside the package tree. So long as you avoid that, there won't be any import errors.

Comment: @DapperDuck I suppose the OP might have a legitimate reason for wanting to run a module/script from *within* their package tree. If they *really* need to do this, they might be able to use e.g. `python -m package.module` (so long as the package is on their PYTHONPATH). But if that's not the case, I think the only remaining option is hacking `sys.path`.